# How to reliably get previous month from js Date?

Tags: javascript, date

What's the better way to get the previous month from a given day in vanilla javascript?

A quick search would tell you to do:

```js
const getPreviousMonth = date => {
  const clone = new Date(date.getTime())
  clone.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1)
  return clone
}
```

The problem being `getPreviousDate(new Date(2021, 4, 31))` returns May 1st, not April 30, which seems to imply it just subtracts 30 days. Curiously, `getPreviousDate(new Date(2021, 2, 1))` correctly return Feb 1st instead of a late date in January, so the 30 days theory is a dud.

Given that, is there a best practice vanilla solution to getPrevious month? Currently, I add a line like: `if (date.getDate() === 31) newDate.setDate(-1)` which returns April 29 (!?). So I'm sure a better solutions exists.

PS.: Just to be clear, I don't want to know what date it was 30 days ago, but what month was the previous month. So to May 31 the answer is April, to March 1, it is February.

**Edit:** Specifically, I want to return a Date object within the previous month, preferably on the last day.

Comment: Moment has (had?) methods like `moment(date).subtract(30, "days")` or `moment(date).subtract(1, "month")`. Not sure what the syntax is in Moment's successor, [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs)

Comment: The previous month is simply `clone.getMonth()`, i.e. `4`.

Comment: It's not as simple as "subtract 30 days". When day of month outside range it will add or subtract the difference.  For example `new Date(2021, 2, 0)` returns last day of february

Comment: What exactly are you needing as result?

Comment: A Date object within the previous month, preferably that last day of the previous month. I get that by adding that if statement, but such a solution makes me suspect I'm missing something. The getMonth behaviour looks unreliable to me.

Comment: What's happening is if you try 31st day of february you end up with last day plus remainder `31-28`  (or 29 in leap year) which pushes it into the next month that many days

Comment: As you said, if it falls outside of range, it will process the difference, which is why Date is so useful. But subtracting a month from May 31 and get May 1 doesn't quite add up to me. Are you suggesting because it falls on April 31 (which doesn't exist) it is pushed to May 1? That is such a bad implementation it's not even funny. It would be the same as interpreting "I must take away 30 days" instead of a month, and thus be incompatible with the February example.

Comment: Date is well known as a poor API in javascript. But yes that's how it works and why setting zero for day of month returns prior month last day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `clone.setDate(0)`  and you will get the last day of previous month

```js
const dates = [new Date(2021,0,15), new Date(2021,2,31)]

const getPreviousMonth = date => {
  const clone = new Date(date)
  clone.setDate(0)
  return clone
}

dates.forEach(d=>{
  console.log(getPreviousMonth(d))
})
```

Comment: So setting 0 instead of -1 sure fixes getting April 29. It works, but still requires a `if (date.getDate() === 31) newDate.setDate(0)`. I sure would appreciate doing away with it.

Comment: Shouldn't need the `if()` if you always want last day of previous month

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you don't need if the function only gets the previous month. That's the example, so you're right. If the functions gives us the -X month, then I can't seem to do away with it. Sorry for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for:

```js
now = new Date();
if (now.getMonth() == 0) {
   var  current = new Date(now.getFullYear() - 1, 11, 1);
} else {
    var current = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth());
}
console.log(current);
```

Comment: That would return undefined for the month before January, which of course, could be fixed. But having the output be a Date is much more convenient. I can easily get the year and localeStrings.